# Can't install ubuntu-desktop after removing unity-scope-*

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, unity-dash

I read that application search in the dash can be sped up by disabling or removing some Unity scopes from it. I was dumb enough to remove all the scopes by running

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-scope*
```

I saw that that caused a removal of a lot of seemingly important packages (e.g. `nautilus`). It did speed up the search, but after restarting, my desktop is broken.

I can see the desktop, but there is no menu bar or launcher. I tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, but that gives me the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've also tried `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop`, but that gives me a similar error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  checkbox-gui checkbox-ng{a} checkbox-ng-service{a} libhud2{a} liboxideqt-qmlplugin{ab} liboxideqtcore0{a} libqt5feedback5{a} libqt5multimedia5{ab} 
  libqt5organizer5{ab} libqt5qml-graphicaleffects{a} libqt5svg5{a} libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin{a} libthumbnailer0{a} libunity-action-qt1{a} libunity-webapps0{a} 
  oxideqt-codecs{a} plainbox-provider-checkbox{a} plainbox-provider-resource-generic{a} plainbox-secure-policy{a} python3-checkbox-ng{a} 
  python3-checkbox-support{a} python3-plainbox{a} python3-pyparsing{a} python3-requests{a} python3-urllib3{a} qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin{a} qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin{a} qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets{a} qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin{ab} qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin{a} ubuntu-desktop 
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme{a} unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml{a} unity-webapps-service{a} webapp-container{ab} webbrowser-app{ab} xul-ext-unity 
  xul-ext-websites-integration{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 41 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 22,3 MB/25,2 MB of archives. After unpacking 99,9 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 webapp-container : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 libqt5organizer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 webbrowser-app : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 libpython3.4-minimal : Breaks: python3-urllib3 (< 1.7.1-1ubuntu4) but 1.7.1-1build1 is to be installed.
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
                                           Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-2-1 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:           
1)      checkbox-gui [Not Installed]                                  
2)      checkbox-ng [Not Installed]                                   
3)      checkbox-ng-service [Not Installed]                           
4)      liboxideqt-qmlplugin [Not Installed]                          
5)      libqt5feedback5 [Not Installed]                               
6)      libqt5multimedia5 [Not Installed]                             
7)      libqt5organizer5 [Not Installed]                              
8)      libunity-webapps0 [Not Installed]                             
9)      python3-checkbox-ng [Not Installed]                           
10)     python3-requests [Not Installed]                              
11)     python3-urllib3 [Not Installed]                               
12)     qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin [Not Installed]              
13)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin [Not Installed]
14)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [Not Installed]       
15)     ubuntu-desktop [Not Installed]                                
16)     unity-webapps-common [Not Installed]                          
17)     unity-webapps-qml [Not Installed]                             
18)     unity-webapps-service [Not Installed]                         
19)     webapp-container [Not Installed]                              
20)     webbrowser-app [Not Installed]                                
21)     xul-ext-unity [Not Installed]                                 
22)     xul-ext-websites-integration [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Selecting 'y' results in

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I've reset my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
```

and I've run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` multiple times.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
Here's the output of `apt-cache policy libpython3.4-minimal python3-urllib3 libqt5multimedia5`:

```
libpython3.4-minimal:
  Installed: 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3
  Candidate: 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.4.0-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64  Packages
python3-urllib3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.7.1-1build1
  Version table:
     1.7.1-1build1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libqt5multimedia5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.1-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
     5.2.1-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: @Tim I did try that, and the first error listed above is from `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: sorry yes... didn't read well enough

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` recently? All the `qt*-abi-*` packages with version numbers in the package names look like they may have been introduced recently by an ABI upgrade of the  Qt library. I would also like to see the output of `apt-cache policy libpython3.4-minimal python3-urllib3 libqt5multimedia5` to see whether PPA may be a cause for the package dependency issues.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've added the output of the command. I've ran `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` multiple times. I've also reset my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use only `main` and `universe` (also added to question).

Comment: The installed packages are inconsistent with those in the `trusty` repository. `libpython3.4-minimal=3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3` is from `trusty-updates` (compare with [my `apt-cache policy`](//paste.ubuntu.com/15327224/)), which is not part of your package sources. That's why it breaks all available versions of `python3-urllib3`. I recommend that you either downgrade all packages that are newer than those in the enabled repositories or that you re-enable the `trusty-updates` repository. Try to install `ubuntu-desktop` again and report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
sudo dpkg -a --configure    
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: I've tried that. Unity is installed fine. I believe the problem is that `ubuntu-desktop` is not and cannot be installed.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this through synaptic ?

Comment: I did, it shows `ubuntu-desktop` as broken so it can't do anything.

Comment: Have a look here: http://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/